# Is it possible to populate a company's information (phone, website, address) when creating lead record

Tags: rest-api, api, leads, appexchange

I am trying to populate data on leads (or any object) when a user creates a new record.  For example:

When a user types in "Test Company" and creates the record, "Test Company's" data like phone, website, and address will be populated when the record is created.  Is there a way  to do that natively or will I have to use a trigger with a callout to a Google API.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Up until a couple of weeks ago, you could use the [Data.com Clean](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.data_dot_com_clean_clean_overview.htm&type=5) solution that was offered by salesforce.com. This has been discontinued and will not be available going forward, unfortunately. However, there are a number of [alternative providers](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxStore?type=Data) that you can subscribe to in order to automatically populate this data from various sources. Of course, it's also possible to build your own integrations, it just might take a bit of development time to get it off the ground. If you can afford it, the solutions on the AppExchange should get you where you want to go, otherwise you can build your own solution.